# Finding the outflow density of a steady-state system with constant volume

Tags: calculus, fluid-dynamics, chemistry

> Consider a steady-state system with constant volume, a single constant
> inflow, and a single constant outflow, but with spatially varying fluid
> density within the system. Use the following equation
> $$
> V \frac {\mathrm d\rho_{\text{sys}}}{\mathrm dt} +  \rho_{\text{sys}} \frac{\mathrm dV}{\mathrm dt} = \sum_{i=1}^{N}Q_{\text{in},i}\rho_{\text{in},i} - \sum_{j=1}^{M}Q_{\text{out},j}\rho_{\text{out},j}
> $$
> to derive a simple formula for the outflow density if $Q_{\text{in}}$, $Q_{\text{out}}$, and $\rho_{\text{in}}$ are known.

I was able to reason that if the volume of the system is constant, than the derivative of volume with respect to time should be zero, giving the following equation.
$$
V \frac {\mathrm d\rho_{\text{sys}}}{\mathrm dt}  = Q_{\text{in}}\rho_{\text{in}} - Q_{\text{out}}\rho_{\text{out}}
$$
At this point, I'm not exactly sure what to do. I thought that maybe since there was constant volume and steady state conditions that
$$
Q_{\text{in}} = Q_{\text{out}}
$$
However I'm now pretty sure that that would only be the case in a system with constant density. I'm not exactly sure where to go next.

Comment: What kind of system is this ? Is this system one-dimensional? What is the physical description of it, if there is one?